# pgAdmin 4 Why is text corrupted on error?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

[image]

I am posting this on Stack Overflow because I cannot find anything about this anywhere on the internet. Sometimes errors I get have corrupted text and are therefore unreadable, thus I can't even figure out what the problem is.

This is a fresh install of PostgreSQL, with locale set to "C" and language set to English. I tried changing Windows language (it was previously Japanese), but that didn't work.

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The error comes from PostgreSQL server. pgAdmin just shows it. Try connecting it with psql once. If you get the same result, then probably you need to tag postgresql.

Comment: @AdityaToshniwal Thank you for the observation. I noticed that when getting an error in psql it is in Japanese, regardless of me changing the Windows display language. I'm starting to think pgadmin cannot display unicode in error texts. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Well, it should be able to show the Japanese texts. pgAdmin itself also supports Japanese language. But since this error comes from PostgreSQL via psycopg3 python driver to pgAdmin, I'm not entirely sure of the bug. You can report this here - https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/new